# Xamarin form: How to find out the android device's size bucket e.g small, medium etc

Tags: android, xamarin, screen, simulator

Trying to create a new android device from Xamarin IDE. I try to create a simulator with the similar spec as Galaxy Tab S2. How do I find out the Size bucket of that device, the screen ratio, and density.

[image]

Comment: You can try downloading Screen Size (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.screensize&hl=it) and check out what are the exact dimensions, densities and so on.

Comment: thanks but I don't have the device so I need to create a simulator to map it.

Comment: @LittleFunny Did my answer not help?

Answer (score 0):

Via [Android Central](https://www.androidcentral.com) (which will typically have the resolution and screen size specs for most devices).

> The Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 .... with the 8-inch version ... and the 9.7-inch version getting a weight of 389 g. Both versions have a Super AMOLED display with a resolution of 2048x1536.

Via Android's [Screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes):

[image]

So,

- Resolution of: `2048 x 1536` for either size
- DPI of : `256` for 8", `211` for 9.7"
- Size: `xlarge`

Which places one device in `mdpi` and one in `hdpi` based resources.

> mdpi:  Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
>   hdpi:  Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).

re: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities